# Hugo: Translate filesystem paths to site paths (i.e. like jekyll-relative-links

Tags: jekyll, hugo

I'm trying to migrate my blog from Jekyll to Hugo. I'd like to be able to follow links between posts and pages pre-compilation.

This requires that compilation translates relative filesystem links to site links (relative or absolute doesn't matter to me).

I can accomplish this in Jekyll with [jekyll-relative-links](https://github.com/benbalter/jekyll-relative-links). Is there an equivalent option for Hugo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A delightful person made a module for this
https://github.com/danielfdickinson/link-handling-mod-hugo-dfd

Looks a bit new yet, but it worked for me. It even provides compile-time checking that the linked file exists!